# Apply Expression if Checked Checkbox > 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

http://plnkr.co/edit/AxBJs2XICPtWaA7bup8G?p=preview

```
<li ng-repeat="d in data"><input type="checkbox"/>{{$index}}</li>
<button ng-show="checkismorethanone">Save</button>
```

I can't use ng-model because it will check all the checkbox. How can I know if there's any of the checkbox checked? I want to show the save button if anyone of the checkbox is checked, or hide the button if no more button is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2G1vlesd6sCxMYIH77EX?p=preview)

You need an object, say `results', to store the`model`values of your selection. Use`ng-model`to bind the`$index-th`checkbox to`results[$index]`.

```
<li ng-repeat="d in data"><input ng-model="results[$index]" value="{{d}}" type="checkbox"/>{{$index}}</li>
<button ng-show="checkismorethanone">Save</button>
{{ results | json }}
<button ng-show="showButton()">Submit</button>
```

In controller, The `for` loop iterates current selections to check whether some checkbox is checked. `ng-show` is `true` if any of the checkboxes is checked.

```
$scope.results = {};
$scope.showButton = function () {
  for (var key in $scope.results) {
    if ($scope.results[key]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

Toggle the status of the submit button depending on the value of `results`.

Comment: What is this? I want to show the button if there's any checked button else hide the button.

Comment: Well, check my updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2G1vlesd6sCxMYIH77EX?p=preview) and the updated answer.

Comment: what does the for in do? and why u need to init results as an empty object first?

Comment: Please check my answer updated. The `empty object` is to create an empty object, otherwise `$scope.results` is `undefined` and cannot be binded through `results[$index]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
 <li ng-repeat="d in data"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="d.val"/>{{$index}}</li>
<button ng-show="anyCheckBoxSelected()">Save</button>
```

And this in the controller file :

```
$scope.data = [{val:false, num:1 },{num:2, val: false},{num:3, val:false},{num:4, val:false}];
$scope.anyCheckBoxSelected = function() {
  var checked = $filter("filter")($scope.data , {val:true} );
  return checked.length;
}
```

Here is the plnkr, forked from your link : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/VApxbuEBUljkJDjSusxw

Comment: What if I have no controller over $scope.data? imagine it as external API.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a single variable to count the click,

If a checkbox is `checked` the `increment` the counter, if `checkbox` is not checked `decrement` the counter.

Show the button if `counter count` is greater then 0.

//index.html

```
 <ul >
    <li ng-repeat="d in data" > 
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{$index}}" ng-click="checkboxOnClick($event)" /> {{$index}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-show="checkCount">Save</button>
```

//app.js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [1,2,3,4];

  $scope.checkCount = 0;

  $scope.checkboxOnClick = function($event){
    if( $event.target.checked){
        $scope.checkCount++;
    }else{
        $scope.checkCount--;
    }

  };

});
```

Check the plnkr,

http://plnkr.co/edit/KolYTZjzPvlyUGNF6elZ?p=preview